# Issue in modifying newly inserted element properties in DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, insertafter

I have a function for a button which is called on click event like this.Once clicked,a copy of  element is inserted immediate after the row of the clicked button.I need to change the ID and name of some  elements in the newly inserted row.

```
<tr class="tr_38">
       <td>Maths [ Math01 ]</td>
       <td>Required</td>
       <td>
            <select style="width: 250px;" name="TeacherID[2318]" id="TeacherID[2318]">
            <option selected="" value="132">Dawn Herus - [ID : 132]</option>
            <option value="246">Margaret Wilson - [ID : 246]</option>
            </select>
       </td>
       <td>
            <input class="date hasDatepicker" id="ExamDate_2318" name="ExamDate[2318]" value="02/28/2017"  type="text">
            <input style="width: 100px;" id="ExamTime_2318" name="ExamTime[2318]" value="8:00" type="text">
       </td>
       <td><input value="+" class="more-38-0 more_button" type="button">
       </td>
      </tr>
```

Jquery function:

```
 var counter = -1;
    $(document).on ('click','.more_button',function(){
        var courseID='';
        var row_classname =  $(this).closest('tr').prop('class');
        $.each($(this).prop('class').split(' '), function(i, name) {
            if (name.indexOf('more-') > -1) {
                courseID = name.split('-')[1];
                return false;
            }
        });
          var newrow = '<tr class="'+row_classname+'"><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').text()+
          '</td><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(1)').text()+
          '</td><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(2)').html()+'</td><td>'+
          $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(3)').html()+'</td><td><input type="button" value="+" class="more-'+
          courseID+'-1 more_button"><input type="button" class="remove" value="X">'+
          '</td></tr>';

          $newrow = $(newrow);
          $(newrow).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
          $newrow.find('td:eq(2)').find('select').prop('id','TeacherID['+counter+']');//.prop('name','TeacherID['+counter+']');
          alert($newrow.find('td:eq(2)').html());
          $newrow.find('td:eq(3)').find('input[id^="ExamDate_"]').prop('id','ExamDate_'+counter).prop('name','ExamDate['+counter+']');
          $newrow.find('td:eq(3)').find('input[id^="ExamTime_"]').prop('id','ExamTime_'+counter).prop('name','ExamTime['+counter+']');
          alert($newrow.find('td:eq(3)').html());
          $(this).hide();
          counter--;
    });
```

When I check alert() after modifying the ID and name of  elements,the alert is showing chaned values,but the DOM is not changed.

**FIDDLE**https://jsfiddle.net/anazvak/r3qhokqn/6/

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 sorry i didnt get u.

Comment: Modifying your code right now.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 Thanks for your support bro..waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var counter = -1;
        $(document).on ('click','.more_button',function(){
            var courseID='';
            var row_classname =  $(this).closest('tr').prop('class');
            $.each($(this).prop('class').split(' '), function(i, name) {
                if (name.indexOf('more-') > -1) { // or name.indexOf('toaster') === 0
                    courseID = name.split('-')[1];
                    return false;
                }
            });
              var newrow = $('<tr class="'+row_classname+'"><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').text()+
              '</td><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(1)').text()+
              '</td><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(2)').html()+'</td><td>'+
              $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(3)').html()+'</td><td><input type="button" value="+" class="more-'+
              courseID+'-1 more_button"><input type="button" class="remove" value="X">'+
              '</td></tr>');
              var $newrow = $(newrow);
  $newrow.find('td:eq(2)').find('select').prop('id','TeacherID['+counter+']').prop('name','TeacherID['+counter+']');
              //alert($newrow.find('td:eq(2)').html()); 
              $newrow.find('td:eq(3)').find('input[id^="ExamDate_"]').prop('id','ExamDate_'+counter).prop('name','ExamDate['+counter+']');
              $newrow.find('td:eq(3)').find('input[id^="ExamTime_"]').prop('id','ExamTime_'+counter).prop('name','ExamTime['+counter+']');
              $(newrow).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
              $(this).hide();
              counter--;
        });
        
        $(document).on ('click','.remove',function(){
            var length = 0;
            $('.'+$(this).closest('tr').prop('class')).not(this.closest('tr')).each(function(){
                if($(this).find('td:eq(4)').find('.more_button:visible').length)
                {
                    length += $(this).find('td:eq(4)').find('.more_button:visible').length;  
                }
            });
            if(length == 0)
            {
                $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:eq(4)').find(':hidden').show();
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="tr_38">
                                                    <td>Maths [ Math01 ]</td>
                                                    <td>Required</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select style="width: 250px;" name="TeacherID[2318]" id="TeacherID[2318]"><option selected="" value="132">Dawn Herus - [ID : 132]</option><option value="246">Margaret Wilson - [ID : 246]</option></select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="date hasDatepicker" id="ExamDate_2318" name="ExamDate[2318]" value="02/28/2017"  type="text">
                                                        <input style="width: 100px;" id="ExamTime_2318" name="ExamTime[2318]" value="8:00" type="text">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td><input value="+" class="more-38-0 more_button" type="button"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="tr_290">
                                                    <td>Arabic 2 [ Arab 2 ]</td>
                                                    <td>Elective</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select style="width: 250px;" name="TeacherID[2326]" id="TeacherID[2326]"></select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="date hasDatepicker" id="ExamDate_2326" name="ExamDate[2326]" value="02/28/2017"  type="text">
                                                        <input style="width: 100px;" id="ExamTime_2326" name="ExamTime[2326]" value="8:00"  type="text">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td><input value="+" class="more-290-0 more_button" type="button"></td>
                                                </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/r3qhokqn/7/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you still have some issues with your logic but this should get you started on the right track and clean up some of your code.

Replace your `.more_button` function with this one:

```
$(document).on ('click','.more_button',function(){
    var courseID='';
    var row_classname =  $(this).closest('tr').prop('class');
    $.each($(this).prop('class').split(' '), function(i, name) {
      if (name.indexOf('more-') > -1) { // or name.indexOf('toaster') === 0
          courseID = name.split('-')[1];
          return false;
      }
    });

    var closestTr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var newrow = closestTr.clone();

    $(newrow).insertAfter(closestTr);

    var $newrow = $($(closestTr).next()); // Get the row you just added

    // set the id and name
    $newrow
    .find('td:eq(2) select')
        .prop('id','TeacherID['+counter+']')
          .prop('name','TeacherID['+counter+']');

    alert($newrow
          .find('td:eq(2)')
              .html());

    $newrow
    .find('td:eq(3) input[id^="ExamTime_"]')
        .prop({
               'id' : 'ExamTime_'+counter, 
               'name':'ExamTime['+counter+']'
             });

    alert($newrow
          .find('td:eq(3)')
            .html());

    $(this).hide();
    counter--;
});
```

Since you're just copying an element that's already on the DOM you can replace your logic to recreate the element with the JQuery's `clone` method. You then insert the newly cloned row after your current row and update its properties.

Notice I changed both your `find` and `prop` calls to be more concise. Having a space between elements in your JQuery selector (the stuff between the `$(` and `)`) will tell JQuery to find the first one and inside of that element, no matter how many children you must traverse, find the second element specified, then the third if present, and so on). The brace notation in the `prop` method tells JQuery you are passing multiple props to be updated in the form of an object.